# unable to start process dotnet.exe - input or output cannot be redirected because the specified file is invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

Trying to run run a string as an argument and getting this error

[image]

If I use between quotation marks he adds another slash.

I don't wanna use split or replace, that's a way to use scape in here?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks! that worked, I don't know much about StackOverflow, how can I point to your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional slash you see (probably in the debugger or locals windows) is only displayed to inform you that the first one is not meant as an escape character.

The string itself does only contain one single slash.